# Acces a broken screen android phone with PC

Tags: android, windows, adb, exploit, recovery

is there a way to recover some pictures inside my phone ?
(2 phones actually, Galaxy A5 and A50)

-the screen is broken
-i tried ADB, but device unauthorized

Comment: hello can you acces your samsung kies application on your phone? and phone is have a screenlock?

Comment: If your screen is not working, but if it's just visible enough to see clicks to figure out what's going on, you can try a USB keyboard mouse using type A to type c(or whatever port is on your phone). You can then transfer whatever you want from your phone to other phone using any wireless fileshare method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only method I can think of is using some ADB magic. But if your screen is completely broken, there is no way of allowing a connection between your computer and the device. If by chance you have ever enabled debugging over USB in your phone, try to find the same computer you used when first enabling it, this can be your only chance.
Depending on the Phone vendor additional methods can be available, but they usually involve downloading some app and, again, authorizing connection over Wi-Fi, USB or whatever.
If you really need those files, the only way out might me fixing your screen.